# How to clear Microsoft App Center last session crash report?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

In my Xamarin.Forms App I'm checking if the app closed unexpected on start:

```
if (Crashes.HasCrashedInLastSessionAsync().Result)
{
      var report = Crashes.GetLastSessionCrashReportAsync().Result;
      HandleException("Crash report", report.Exception);
}
```

When I start the app, after an unhandled Exception occurred, the *HasCrashedInLastSessionAsync* method always returns true.

My question now is: How can I clear the last session crash report manually?

Comment: I worked around the problem by storing the last report id and comparing on start. If somebody has a better solution, please let me know.